# How can I solve the problem that bzr cannot acquire lock?

Tags: bazaar

I executed the following command:

```
bzr push lp:~orschiro/+junk/audio-recorder
```

It produces the following error:

```
bzr: ERROR: Could not acquire lock "(remote lock)": bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/~orschiro/%2Bjunk/audio-recorder/
```

I tried to remove the lock as follows:

```
bzr break-lock https://code.launchpad.net/~orschiro/+junk/audio-recorder
```

**However, I still do the same error. How do I properly remove the break-lock?**

Comment: Possible bug? see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/1110065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the lock over ssh rather than http (which doesn't provide write access on launchpad):

```
bzr break-lock lp:~orschiro/+junk/audio-recorder
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much, @jelmer! :-)